# Can we give our types in android map

Tags: android, google-maps

```
 StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
 googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
 googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
 googlePlacesUrl.append("&types=" +"hospital");
 googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
 googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + getString(R.string.server_key));
 googlePlacesUrl.append("&types=" +"hospital"); -
```

This works fine, but i need to give my own type like:

```
googlePlacesUrl.append("&types=" +"Urgent Care");
```

When I do like this crash occuring, can anyone please help? or can anyone help me to search our own type in map?

Answer (score 1):

Urgent Care is not in the types list. Refer google Doc [Here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types).

Also you can't give invalid spaces in URL.

Answer (score 0):

**The Space between Urgent Care is showing crash you must URL encoding to specify this. Search URL encoding you get that.**